# How to determine if a given JSON has nested array structure

Tags: java, arrays

I have this structure of Data in the format Map<String, Object> input:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "title": "Schema",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "uniqueTxnId": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "countryCode": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "url": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "reference": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "reason": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "audit":[
    {
        "docType":"",
        "date":"",
        "status":"",
        "reason":"",
        "remarks":""
        
    },
"docType":"",
        "date":"",
        "status":"",
        "reason":"",
        "remarks":""]
  }
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is I am trying to determine if this structure has any values starting with '['. Basically, an array so that we can loop over the list and get the values. The reason is we want to keep this logic as much generic as possible and don't want to hardcode any keys.

So what I have tried till now is:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : input.entrySet()) {
                if(entry.getValue() instanceof JSONArray && entry.getValue().toString().startsWith("[")) {
                    List<Object> list = (List<Object>) entry.getValue();
                    embeddedArrayObjectSize = list.size();
                    System.out.println("Get first element " + list.get(0));
                    System.out.println("List of elements " + list);
                    System.out.println(entry.getKey());
                }
            }
```

But this approach is not working. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "But this approach is not working" - what is the result of this approach? Is there a compiler error, runtime exception, unexpected result...

Comment: Whats JSONArray?

Comment: What did you use to parse the JSON into the Map<String,Object>?  The documentation of that tool should inform you how arrays will be represented in the Map.

Comment: What json parsing library are you using?

Comment: Check jackson library, it should help solve your issue